# HTML abbr and a together

Tags: html

When using abbr and a (acronym and link) together, is there a preferred order should they be nested? Considerations? There is also the little detail about cursor style conflict depending on browser.

```html
<a href="https://bla.com">
 <abbr title="Tooltip">
  This is some content
 </abbr>
</a>
```

or

```html
<abbr title="Tooltip">
 <a href="https://bla.com">
  This is some content
 </a>
</abbr>
```

It seems to look the same here.

Comment: `abbr` marks only text, as link is not part of abbreviation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[According to the standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#phrasing-content), **phrasing content** can only include other **phrasing content**.
The `abbr` tag refers to **phrasing content**, but the `a` tag, [according to the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#phrasing_content), belongs to this category only when it contains other **phrasing content**.

In your example, both options are acceptable (since there is only phrasing content inside `a`), but since the abbreviation is usually an indivisible element, and for uniformity it is probably better:

```
<a href="https://bla.com">
 <abbr title="Tooltip">
  This is some content
 </abbr>
</a>
```

Since there may be such cases:

```
// Good - Concise and semantically correct
<a href="https://bla.com">
 <span>before...</span>
 <abbr title="Tooltip">
  This is some content
 </abbr>
 <span>...after</span>
</a>


// Bad - too fragmented
<a href="https://bla.com">
  <span>before...</span>
</a>
<abbr title="Tooltip">
  <a href="https://bla.com">
    This is some content
  </a>
</abbr>
<a href="https://bla.com">
  <span>...after</span>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no preferred order to arrange them. But it's better to nest them like your first code example. Sometimes, its arrangement depends on the code situation like complexity and the connection between other tags and attributes.

Comment: It looks like you've got the right idea. It might be helpful to add some code examples.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).